# How can I configure Webpack to watch my React bundle for changes and hot reload? (React built into ASP.NET MVC Project)

Tags: c#, reactjs, node.js, asp.net, webpack

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC project that I incorporated with React. I have React working in the project in the sense that I set up the components and see them rendered on my page mixed in with the Razor code, so all is good there, however the hot reload / live feature that we love about React is not working. I tried configuring webpack many different ways, all to no avail.

If this helps, here is a bit of my project hierarchy, specifically where the React stuff is located.

```
Root/
├── Other folders...
├── React/
│   ├── dist/
│   │   └── bundle.js
│   └── src/
│       ├── App.js
│       └── index.js
├── webpack.config.js
├── package.json
├── tsconfig.json
├── global.asax
├── Web.config
```

Along with that, this is how my webpack.config.js is setup.

```
"use strict";
var path = require("path");
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require("webpack-notifier");
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: ["./React/src/index.js"],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./React/dist"),
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: 'auto',
        clean: true
    },
    cache: false,
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                    },
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: [
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin()
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
};
```

and here are my dependencies and devDependencies if that helps.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.13",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-class-properties": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.15",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "react-refresh": "^0.14.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
    },
```

Essentially, what I want is to be able to run my project in Visual Studio and when I make changes to the React components, they update on save, like it would in a create-react-app. I believe this should be possible, but haven't got it to work yet with webpack sadly. If anyone has any starting points or has found a fix I'd greatly appreciate it! Thanks.